Is it possible to disable jQuery function on appear from another js script?
There's a wordpress website. All changes right now are being made in the child theme. On some pages there are sections with Counter Boxes (on appear the numbers start counting from 0 to the given value).

The HTML-code looks like that:
<div class="fusion-column-wrapper">
    <div class="fusion-counters-box counters-box fusion-columns-4">
        <div class="fusion-counter-box fusion-column col-counter-box counter-box-wrapper" data-animationoffset="100%">
            <div class="counter-box-container">
                <div class="content-box-percentage content-box-counter">
                    <i class="counter-box-icon fontawesome-icon fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="display-counter" data-value="87342" data-direction="up" data-decimals="0">87342</span>
                </div>
                <div class="counter-box-content">PLAQUES POSEES</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- other columns -->

    </div>
</div>

It is wanted to disable the animation in all counter boxes anywhere on the website.
The JS script running the animation is found in some plugin provided with the theme.
\wp-content\plugins\fusion-builder....\fusion-counters-box.js
!function (o) { "use strict"; o.fn.$fusionBoxCounting = function () { var n = o(this).data("value"), e = o(this).data("direction"), i = o(this).data("delimiter"), t = 0, u = n, r = fusionCountersBox.counter_box_speed, s = Math.round(fusionCountersBox.counter_box_speed / 100); i || (i = ""), "down" === e && (t = n, u = 0), o(this).countTo({ from: t, to: u, refreshInterval: s, speed: r, formatter: function (o, n) { return "-0" === (o = (o = o.toFixed(n.decimals)).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, i)) && (o = 0), o } }) } }(jQuery), jQuery(window).on("load fusion-element-render-fusion-counters_box", function (o, n) { (void 0 !== n ? jQuery('div[data-cid="' + n + '"]').find(".fusion-counter-box").not(".fusion-modal .fusion-counter-box") : jQuery(".fusion-counter-box").not(".fusion-modal .fusion-counter-box")).each(function () { var o = jQuery(this), n = getWaypointOffset(jQuery(this)); o.waypoint(function () { o.find(".display-counter").each(function (o, n) { jQuery(n).$fusionBoxCounting() }), this.destroy() }, { offset: n }) }), jQuery(".fusion-modal .fusion-counter-box").on("appear", function () { jQuery(this).find(".display-counter").each(function () { jQuery(this).$fusionBoxCounting() }) }) }), jQuery(window).on("fusion-element-render-fusion_counter_box", function (o, n) { jQuery('div[data-cid="' + n + '"]').find(".display-counter").each(function () { jQuery(this).$fusionBoxCounting() }) });

An easy solution is to make the changes in the corresponding file of the plugin. But if it is once updated the changes will be lost.
Another approach is to change the code (for example, change the names of the classes and add the corresponding styling of the new classes).
But I'm wondering, is it possible to add a function into a JS file in the child theme that would disable any other JS function for the corresponding elements? Something like that:
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        /** 
         * Disable Animation
         */

        $(".display-counter").on( "appear", function(){

            jQuery.fx.off = true; // right now it doesn't give any effect

        });

    });

})(jQuery);


You can overwrite an existing and defined function by reassigning it. For the example you gave, the javascript code you will add to the child theme is;
jQuery.fn.$fusionBoxCounting = function(){}

and/or:
$.fn.$fusionBoxCounting = function(){}

However, it may not be a good idea to disable a global function of the site's theme with this method. It may disrupt the operation of something you didn't expect.
I recommend that you delete the display-counter class value of the HTML elements whose animation effect you want to disable, with a javascript code that will be added to the end of the page, but will run before the theme's original javascript file. Something like this:
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("display-counter");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].classList.remove("display-counter");
}


Thank you! Reassigning the function really helped. While now I didn't notice anything unexpected, but I will make more tests on the website. Unfortunately, trying to remove classes worked weirdly: every 2nd element with the class kept the class, I don't see why. Though the same loop doing a different function works perfect (initially, all the numbers are shown as 0, so I change the 0's to the value of the corresponding attribute). Right now the code is the following (I'll send it in the next comment)

$.fn.$fusionBoxCounting = function(){};
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("display-counter");
let value;
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
value = $(elements[i]).attr( "data-value" );
$(elements[i]).text( value );
}
